# Is there any way to control nokia e90 or other phones from computer?

Tags: testing, emulation, nokia

I am trying to develop programs which will work for nokia mobile phones.

I have E90 and want to control it over my computer. 
Or i want to test programs with emulator.

Do you know is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing with emulator is not good. Why don't you try out [DeviceAnywhere](http://www.deviceanywhere.com) OR [Perfecto Mobile Testing Platform](http://www.perfectomobile.com/). They both allow testing of applications on REAL devices through web. You can create a trial account and test your application.

Comment: +1 DeviceAnywhere is also a good service but you have to download so much stuff before testing. I like perfecto's flash interface (no downloads involved) and you can test out functionality. I think Nokia also provides a testing environment free of cost for their phones (Symbian Platform).

Comment: perfecto's flash is free or not?

Comment: Its not free. But there is a trial available. Same is the case with DeviceAnywhere. At DeviceAnywhere there is a special Nokia VDL also available specifically for Nokia Symbian Developers.

Comment: I am working on a in house application to make testing of Symbian Applications easier. The application will allow you to control Symbian phones using the PC. I will release it on http://faisalferoz.wordpress.com in some time. If you can wait for it.